# MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection CustomTabsServiceConnectionImpl that was originally bound here

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, chrome-custom-tabs

xamarin android project unbindservice for  custom tabs.
I am not able to find out the method of unbinding services.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs](https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidSupportComponents/blob/master/customtabs/component/GettingStarted.md) library, please notice that [CustomTabsActivityManager](https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidSupportComponents/blob/master/customtabs/source/Additions/CustomTabsActivityManager.cs) class didn't provide the `UnBindService()` method, and you can't get the `CustomTabsServiceConnection` instance from outside so that it's hard to unbind the service in your Activity.

## Solution：

So you need to add the `UnBindService()` method by yourself, for example:

```
public class MyCustomTabsActivityManager
{
     CustomTabsServiceConnectionImpl connection;

     public Activity ParentActivity { get; private set; }
     public CustomTabsClient Client { get; private set; }

     CustomTabsSession session = null;

     ...

     public void UnBindService()
     {
         if (connection != null)
         {
             ParentActivity.UnbindService(connection);
             Client = null;
             session = null;
          }
     }
}
```

Then, you could use this `UnBindService()` in your `Activity`:

```
protected override void OnDestroy()
{
    myCustomTabsActivityManager.UnBindService();
    base.OnDestroy();
}
```